# Is it appropriate to comment on and base votes on coding practices?

Tags: discussion, code-formatting

Where answers are technically correct but are **(in my opinion)** examples of bad coding practice (for example the `multiline-braceless-if` in `C` and related languages) I tend to comment upon them and if appropriate not up vote them. However, in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16927408/better-way-to-create-a-string-in-java/16927449#16927449) answer a user with considerable reputation stated that comments or not upvoting based on coding standards was not appropriate. So I want to ask:

- Is it appropriate to comment on coding standards of answers which are
  technically correct.
- Is it appropriate to not upvote based upon coding standards (presumably leading to SO gaining its own coding standard organically based on what gets up voted and what doesn't).

Clearly it would not be appropriate to get into an editing war with the original poster, but are votes and comments appropriate?

I don't want this to decend into a discussion as to whether the `multiline-braceless-if` *is* bad practice, just whether it is appropriate to comment either way.

Comment: 10k is not what I'd call considerable reputation, TBH.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Fair enough, considerably more than me then

Comment: Do be careful to distinguish between questions that have code that is coded for brevity and/or clarity for the purpose of the question rather than just being a trough of bad coding practices. And try not to get too nit picky over some things - people have different coding standards and that's just the way it is, you just have to learn to live with.

Comment: Let the holy war on tabs vs. spaces begin!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it appropriate to comment on coding standards of answers which are technically correct.

Sure. If you notice something which can be improved, comments are just fine. If you constructively point things out, there is no problem with that. Try not to draw it out into long discussions or debates, but that's about it.

> Is it appropriate to not upvote based upon coding standards (presumably leading to SO gaining its own coding standard organically based on what gets up voted and what doesn't).

It is entirely up to you to decide how to vote. Heck, you could even downvote correct answers if you don't like the coding practices used. Votes are up to the discretion of the user. Whether or not you feel it's appropriate is entirely up to you to decide.

Answer (score 5):

Your vote is *your vote*. Bottom line.

Leaving a comment to give way to reasoning is a decent courtesy, though.

Answer (score 2):

First, I would say that it is always appropriate to not upvote something that you do not find particularly useful.

Second, I would think that commenting is good - or even better, you might provide another answer with the solution you think is the better/cleaner one.