# What are the bad reasons for downvoting?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I had [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980866/jquery-to-check-if-an-input-has-a-specific-name/18980883?noredirect=1#comment28040131_18980883) a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980866) some time back... and there was another better answer for that question, but mine got accepted and initially there were  some upvotes for it...

But sometime later it started getting more attention and started getting more downvotes mostly because it was a poor answer and the other one was better... but the interesting portion was most of the downvotes was not for the answer, but to give more visibility to the another answer....

Is it justified?

Note: I will be taking down my answer after some time because the other one is better.

Comment: Note that with this meta question you draw attention to the situation from a specific subgroup of SO users (those that read meta), which may influence further voting.

Comment: @Jeroen that is ok.... just want some opinions on the voting practice used there... I'll be taking it down anyways....

Comment: Since the OP accepted your answer, you cannot delete it.

Comment: @Oded Which seems a little cruel, could Arun flag to request a delete? Or a disassociate?

Comment: @RichardTingle - It is indeed an unhappy situation. I've been there myself. But the fact is - the OP decided what answer helped them most and that's that.

Comment: He can ask for disassociation, though (using the "contact" link; mods can't do that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "good" reason for downvoting someone's post is because it is genuinely bad. Now, there is a certainly an element of subjectivity involved, because what feels "genuinely bad" to one person may not be so to a second person, and may even sound "pretty good" to a third person, who will downvote, not vote, and upvote respectively. This part is all "honor system," and assumes that everyone is voting their genuine convictions, as they might for a political candidate.

A bad reason for downvoting is for an answer that is OK, but not as good as some other. Then the proper course is to "not vote" for one, and upvote the other.

The worst reason for downvoting is "personal" downvoting, where one downvotes the person, rather than the post.

You don't need to remove your post just because you think someone else's is better, but if you do, you'll earn the "disciplined" badge if it has three or more (net) upvotes.

Answer (score 6):

There are no good or bad reasons for voting, fraud aside, a person's vote is their own to do with as they see fit. Of course there is [advice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19268/how-should-down-voting-be-used) on how most people vote, but that is merely advice and is not binding

For example I downvote technically correct but misleading answers. Other people may vote based upon coding conventions they like. It is all valid because your vote is your vote.

The only caveat is that you should vote for the content not for the person (hence voting fraud)

Comment: but the policy says something else isn't it http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Comment: Thats more advice than policy, how you should vote comes up often and is always the same answer, eg http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183460/is-it-appropriate-to-comment-on-and-base-votes-on-coding-practices

Comment: also... I've something like 50+ votes for the day... the rep cap was reached already... but now it is not taking 200 points it is showing 200- downvotes why is it.... any idea?

Comment: [These](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70158/what-if-i-hit-the-daily-rep-cap-and-then-get-downvoted) two [posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132715/do-the-order-in-which-upvotes-downvotes-given-in-a-day-also-matter-towards-rep-l) suggest that you have to get annother upvote to counter the downvotes, but if even [Anna Lear is uncertain](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132715/do-the-order-in-which-upvotes-downvotes-given-in-a-day-also-matter-towards-rep-l#comment367577_132716) then I'm not going to give a definitive answer

Comment: I would disagree that there are no good or bad *reasons* for voting, but, aside from clearly fraudulent patterns, there is no way to judge a user's reasons (be they good or bad) and thus, in practice, people may vote for any reason they want to.